# Dynamic Controls Creation C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls

let me explain what I'm trying to do:
I need to create new controls dynamically from my db source.
I've wrote this code below, but the code returns only the 1st row value "x" times present in the table db, where "x" is the maximum row number. So, I think I've missing some in control definition. Can you help me?

```
string constring = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", AcessoBancoDados.server, AcessoBancoDados.user, AcessoBancoDados.password, AcessoBancoDados.database);

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = constring;
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblclientes";
        cmd.Connection = con;

        MySqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = rd.FieldCount;
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Name = count.ToString();
                lbl.Location = new Point(10, 10+20*i);
                lbl.Text = rd[1].ToString();
                lbl.AutoSize = true;
                lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }
        }

        con.Close();
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Found error, I've not set this labels into a flow layout panel!

Comment: You are putting all of the labels there, but putting them on top of each other so you can't see them. The bug is on this line - `lbl.Location = new Point(10, 10+20*i);`.

Comment: Ok, thank you mjwills!
I've found the error. This labels aren't in a flow panel, so, the're pulling each other in top.